# Is there a PipelineDB package for Laravel or Native PHP?

Tags: pipelinedb

I was asking for PipelineDB if there is a package for laravel or Native PHP, so I can use it in my current project?

Answer (score 0):

PipelineDB actually does not have its own special client libraries but instead maintains compatibility with all PostgreSQL clients. Any client that works with PostgreSQL will seamlessly work with PipelineDB, so you're free to use the PHP/PostgreSQL client of your choice.

Please see the [clients](http://docs.pipelinedb.com/clients.html) section of the PipelineDB docs for more information.